# Cluster Sessions Not replicated to group Nodes

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, session-replication

I have two tomcat nodes with both servers up.

when I shut down one server I get the following exception and the session is not replicated. I have to login again, Have I missed some steps?

```
   WARNING: IOException in replication worker, unable to drain channel. Probable cause: Keep alive socket closed[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host].
May 3, 2012 2:15:02 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask run
WARNING: IOException in replication worker, unable to drain channel. Probable cause: Keep alive socket closed[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host].
[
```

Comment: Without knowing what steps you have taken, your question is pretty much impossible to answer other than with a "Yes, because clustering works for me"

Comment: I have followed steps mention in following link  http://www.jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2009/07/apache-tomcat-clustering-load-balancing.html I am getting  IOException in replication worker

Answer (score 1):

This is just warning, nothing wrong in configuration.
When you shutdown one tomcat instance this warning appears.

Mostly you have not marked application as distributable.

Add `<distributable />` tag in web.xml of the given application.